# Resize a group of variably sized images both horizontally & vertically - need help optimising

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

WARNING CODE CRASHES IN EVERYTHING EXCEPT GOOGLE CHROME

I'm trying to create a feature on our website that takes 8 random images and places them in two rows and dynamically resizes the images to take up the full width of the page.

I've created a jsbin for this to try and demonstrate the issue.

https://jsbin.com/yijemazovi/edit?html,css,js,output

The comments in the code should give you an good idea of what I'm doing. What seems to be happening for everything but Google Chrome is that the while condition is never satisfied so it goes on infinitely and crashes the browser.

Perhaps it is something as simple as I am doing the do/while loop incorrectly or I should just be using a while loop???

Any help is appreciated!

```
/*****
 * Get the overall width of the container that we want to match
 **********/
var ContainerWidth = $('.feature-inim-collage .col.span_1_of_1').width();


/*****
 * Increase the height of the images until the total sum of the width 
 * if the 4 images + the gutters is larger than ContainerWidth - then 
 * stop
 **********/

/*****
 * Increment in jumps of 10px until we get within 80% of the width of 
 * the ContainerWidth and then go to a more precise increment of 1px.
 * We can increase the px from 10 to 20 or 30 so there are less loops
 * but this can cause issues when we look at mobile and there is less
 * overall width in the containers and jumping by 30px will be too much
 **********/
var i = 0;
do {
  $('.feature-inims-top-row .growable-container').css('height', i);
  var RowWidth1 = CalculateTotalWidth(1);
  if(RowWidth1 < (ContainerWidth*0.8)){
    i = i+10;
  }else{
    i++;
  }
}
while (RowWidth1 < (ContainerWidth - 3));

/*****
 * Repeat above for the 2nd row
 **********/
var i = 0;
do {
  $('.feature-inims-bottom-row .growable-container').css('height', i);
  var RowWidth2 = CalculateTotalWidth(2);
  if(RowWidth2 < (ContainerWidth*0.8)){
    i = i+10;
  }else{
    i++;
  }
}
while (RowWidth2 < (ContainerWidth - 3));

/*********
 * Calculate the combined width of the images + the gutters
 ****/
function CalculateTotalWidth(Row) {
  var Image1Width = $('.growable-container-1').width();
  var Image2Width = $('.growable-container-2').width();
  var Image3Width = $('.growable-container-3').width();
  var Image4Width = $('.growable-container-4').width();
  var Image5Width = $('.growable-container-5').width();
  var Image6Width = $('.growable-container-6').width();
  var Image7Width = $('.growable-container-7').width();
  var Image8Width = $('.growable-container-8').width();
  var GutterSize = 24; // (3 gutters @ 8px each)

  if(Row == 1){
    var RowWidth = GutterSize + Image1Width + Image2Width + Image3Width + Image4Width;
  }else{
    var RowWidth = GutterSize + Image5Width + Image6Width + Image7Width + Image8Width;
  }
  return RowWidth
}
```

Comment: It seems that the issue might lie with the `CalculateTotalWidth()` as this value doesn't seem to change when the code loops

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue with this was that in the CalculateTotalWidth() function I was checking the width of the container the image was in rather than the image itself. As soon as I changed this it worked perfectly.

```
var Image1Width = $('.growable-container-1 img').width();
```

instead of

```
var Image1Width = $('.growable-container-1').width();
```